# How do I localize page layouts and masterpages in a sandboxed solution?

Tags: master-page, page-layout, sandbox-solution, localization

In farm solutions you can use resource files inside aspx-pages by deploying resx-files to the hive. MSDN have some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615453%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but there's no example for page layouts, just managed code which is deprecated in sandboxed solutions.

Is there a way to localize page layouts (html or aspx) in sandboxed solution without using managed code?

EDIT: I have added a request on [uservoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/5622159-enable-localization-of-page-layouts-and-masterpage), feel free to vote on it!

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this article in MSDN. It'll outline to you the procedures and limitations about localizing Sandboxed solutoins (same applies to SP 2013):

[Localization of Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615460%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I've created a satelite assembly added the namespace to a aspx page layout `<%@ Import Namespace="LocalizePageLayout" %>` and attempted to print it like `<%= Properties.Resources.HelloWorld %>`.

I get the yellow screen of death saying "Code blocks are not allowed in this file.".

Comment: Have you tried `<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyResources,Foo%>" />`? Note that using a farm solution for localization breaks your sandboxed approach as you are not sandboxed anymore.